# Meaning of $\iint_\mathbb{D} |f^{'}(z)|^2dxdy$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

For an Analytic isomorphism $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$  ,where $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disc and $\mathbb{S}^1$ is the unit square.

Given that $ f(0)=\frac{1+i}{2}$.

And in the middle of an answer to a different question, I got stuck at this point
$$\iint_\mathbb{D} |f'(z)|^2dxdy$$ Wonder whether this could be reduced down to a simpler meaning such as the area of the unit disc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ as $f(x,y)=\left(\begin{array}{c}u(x,y)\\ v(x,y)\end{array}\right)\in\Bbb R^2$, we obtain the Jacobian matrix as follows.$$
Df=\left(\begin{array}{cc}u_x(x,y)&u_y(x,y)\\ v_x(x,y)&v_y(x,y)\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}u_x(x,y)&-v_x(x,y)\\ v_x(x,y)&u_x(x,y)\end{array}\right),
$$where the second equality comes from the Cauchy-Riemann equation $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y+v_x=0$. It should be noted that $$\det (Df)=u_x^2+v_x^2=|u_x+iv_x|^2=|f'(x+iy)|^2.$$ If $f$ is an injective mapping, then change of variable formula on $\Bbb R^2$ gives that
$$
\text{Area}(f(\Bbb D))=\int_{f(\Bbb D)}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=\int_{\Bbb D} |\det(Df)|\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=\int_{\Bbb D}|f'(x+iy)|^2\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\tag{*}
$$ i.e. the expression in $(*)$ is equal to the area of the range of $f$. Even if $f$ is not injective, $(*)$ can be seen as the area of $f(\Bbb D)$ 'counted with multiplicity'. (In this regard, $(*)$ somehow measures the 'magnitude' of $f$ modulo constant.)

Comment: Thank you!
Can you please mention a source for me to refer the change of variable formula on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: You can find it on this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution). I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you! yes it did